# Is it possible to throttle the bacon action `repeatedly` somehow?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, frp, bacon.js

I am using bacon.js and have some situation where signal is emitted from two sources:

```
sourceA :: EventStream a
sourceB :: EventStream Bool
```

When `sourceA` is fired, it should trigger some action that runs `repeatedly` onto perpetuity, except when a signal is fired from `sourceB`. So syntactically it might look like this:

```
aAction = sourceA
    . repeatedly (200, [1,2,3])
    . until      (sourceB)
```

So I'm basically asking for an analogue to `takeWhile` or `takeUntil` combinators, but can't find such a function in the source or documentation. Any thoughts?

It'd be even better if there's a generic combinator

```
throttleWhen :: Bool -> EventStream a
```

or

```
throttleWhen' :: EventStream Bool -> EventStream a
```

that terminates any bacon event stream on some condition, how would I go about implementing such a thing?

Note, this solution below:

```
faAction = sourceA  . repeatedly (200, [1,2,3])
aAction  = faAction . takeUntil  (sourceB)
```

throttles the derived stream `aAction`, but not the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you're looking for a combinator that ends a stream when a truthy value appears in another stream. You can use `a.takeUntil(b.filter(Bacon._.id))` to end a stream when a truthy value appears on `b`. If `b` is a Property, the result will end immediately in case `b` holds a truthy value at start.

You solution might look like this.

```
aAction = sourceA
  .flatMap(function() { 
    return Bacon.repeatedly (200, [1,2,3]) 
      .takeUntil(sourceB.filter(Bacon._.id))
  })
```

This one will start a new stream for each element of `sourceA` and terminate that when a truthy value appears `sourceB`.

Or, you can `a.takeWhile(b.not())` if `b` is a Property. Ends immediately if Property has a truthy value to start with.

So, if `sourceB` is a Property holding true/false and you want to be emitting values only when it holds `false`, you can

```
aAction = sourceA
  .flatMap(function() { 
    return Bacon.repeatedly (200, [1,2,3]) 
      .takeWhile(sourceB.not())
  })
```

Comment: I guess I have a lapse in concept and knowlege of Bacon's implementation here. Is `Bacon.repeatedly(200,[1..3])` an action that lazily generates an infinite stream of values? So in your example once values are no longer requested by the action `takeUntil(...)`, no more value is generated by `Bacon.repeatedly`?

Comment: You're correct. All the generator functions in Bacon are indeed lazy, as well as should all stream data sources be, so that the stream users don't have to care about resource management. Bacon takes care of allocating resources automatically, based on demand.